# How to change the vector asset source color of an ImageButton?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a standard vector asset for my close button. the close button is being used throughout the app in white, so I can't just change the fillColor. I need it in black, but I'm told to reuse the white one and just tint it black. This is the src asset for an ImageButton, and no manner of tint has worked - ex app:backgroundTint="@color/black" simply makes everything black. Has anyone found a way to do this?

Here's the vector asset:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
  <path
      android:pathData="M13.414,12L19.778,18.364L18.364,19.778L12,13.414L5.636,19.778L4.222,18.364L10.586,12L4.222,5.636L5.636,4.222L12,10.586L18.364,4.222L19.778,5.636L13.414,12Z"
      android:fillColor="#ffffff"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"/>
</vector>
```

I'm trying for a ripple effect here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/white">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item
      android:bottom="4dp"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_bk_close"
      android:left="4dp"
      android:right="4dp"
      android:top="4dp" />
</ripple>
```

and here is the ImageButton

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_exit"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_exit"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/stim_viewer_btn_close"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />
```

Comment: android:fillColor="#ffffff" change that colour

Comment: can't change it there because the asset is being used other places. I need to change the color locally, only in the ImageButton

Comment: android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless". change to         android:background="@null"